# pandas DataFrame remove Index from columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataFrame, such that when I execute:

```
df.columns
```

I get

```
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I need to remove `Index` to have columns as list of strings, and was trying:

```
df.columns = df.columns.tolist()
```

but this doesn't remove `Index`.

Comment: I think you're confusing index, that is a pandas index object, your columns are indeed strings and a list if you call more than one. What are you trying to do?

Comment: df.columns is always of type `pd.Index` no matter if you assign them as list. you can use them as lists where you want to.

Answer (score 1):

`tolist()` should be able to convert the Index object to a list:

```
df1 = df.columns.tolist()
print(df1)
```

or use `values` to convert it to an array:

```
df1 = df.columns.values
```

The `columns` attribute of a pandas dataframe returns an Index object, you cannot assign the list back to the `df.columns` (as in your original code `df.columns = df.columns.tolist()`), but you can assign the list to another variable.

Comment: this is definitely not what the OP wants